# HTML canvas painting start from right rather than top

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html5-canvas

I try to make drawing app on canvas. It works well in full screen but when I set its width and height according to a div container. It didn't work correctly. It starts painting from the right rather than the top left.

Here is my code pen link: https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/pen/GRpGVmG.

```
div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 " id="canvas-container">
<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas></div>
```

```
#canvas-container{
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #f3f6f7;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to offset the mouse position with the `canvas.getBoundingClientRect`

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var container = document.querySelector(".col-md-4");
canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.fillStyle = "red";
c.strokeStyle = "red";
c.lineWidth = 5;
c.lineCap = "round";


function draw(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top

  c.lineTo(x, y);
  c.stroke();
}
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 25px
}

#canvas-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f3f6f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 " id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```